# ¿ Eclipse sigue dando soporte para desarrollo Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse

Estoy instalando Eclipse neon, soy mas desarrollador web y Java, no Android, pero el instalador de eclipse me da la opcion de instalar eclipse para desarrollar aplicaciones Android y tenia entendido que ya no se podia, realmente no desarrollo apps en Android porque Android Studio es demasiado pesado, volver a eclipse podria cambiar eso.

Comment: La verdad con la ultima actualización de android studio, ya no tiene esos problemas de carga como antes, yo usaría AS para programar en android

Comment: Al revisar la respuesta proporcionada por @Elenasys encuentro que la de ella es más acertada que la mía ya que ella verificó la disponibilidad de la descargas (cosa que no llegué a hacer), y mi respuesta podría producir confusión para algunos al señalar que sí es posible seguir trabajando sin problema con el plug-in ADT para Eclipse, por lo tanto voy a eliminar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NO**, el soporte para el plugin para Eclipse termino, por esa razón se tiene como IDE oficial [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419). No habrá actualizaciones del plugin.

De hecho si hay una adecuación para que trabaje no es oficial.

> [We announced that we were ending development and official support for
>   the Android Developer Tools (ADT) in Eclipse at the end of 2015,
>   including the Eclipse ADT plugin and Android Ant build system. With
>   the latest updates to Studio, we've completed the transition.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

Podrías usar el plugin pero tendrías que usar ADT version 21, lo cual no es compatible con componentes nuevos, sería un dolor de cabeza, sin duda la opción es usar **Android Studio**

@RicardoGabriel si el sitio oficial indica que el ide oficial es Android Studio y además indica que el soporte al ADT termino, creo que la opción sin duda es usar Android Studio.

---

Incluso la versión de Eclipse para trabajar con Android no esta disponible:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/M6/eclipse-android-neon-M6-win32-x86_64.zip

> Eclipse downloads - file unavailable
>
> The selected file is invalid, or it is no longer available for
>   download.
>
> This happens when the file is part of a nightly or development build.
>   If so, please return to the project's home page and download a newer
>   version.